# Angular5: ngOnInit is only invoked once on routing

Tags: angular, angular5, ngoninit

I have this basic app where I grab data from a firestore with a data service. I have several pages(components), teams, players, statistics...

for instance my team component:

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TeamsService } from '../../services/teams.service';
import { Team } from '../../models/team';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-teams',
  templateUrl: './teams.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teams.component.css']
})
export class TeamsComponent implements OnInit {


  public teams: Team[];
  editState: boolean = false;
  teamToEdit: Team;
  showAdd: boolean = false;
  showSelect: boolean = false;
  selectedTeam: Observable<Team>;

  constructor(public teamsService: TeamsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

          this.teamsService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
            this.teams = teams;
            console.log('ngOnInit invoked');
          });
        }


  deleteTeam(event, team) {
    const response = confirm('are you sure you want to delete?');
    if (response) {
      this.teamsService.deleteTeam(team);
    }
    return;
  }

  editTeam(event, team) {
    this.editState = !this.editState;
    this.teamToEdit = team;
  }

  updateTeam(team) {
    this.teamsService.updateTeam(team);
    this.teamToEdit = null;
    this.editState = false;
  }

  showAddForm() {
      this.showAdd = !this.showAdd;
    }

  getTeam(event, team) {
    this.showSelect = !this.showSelect;
    this.selectedTeam = this.teamsService.getTeamById(team.id);
  }
}
```

In the ngOnInit I load my data into the local variables, but once i navigate away to another page and then come back the data is gone. I literally need to refresh the page to reload the data.

How should I solve this?

Comment: That lifecycle hook only triggers the first time the component is initialised, see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks for details.

Comment: put the console.log outside of the subscription to see if its really not invoked or if its a problem with the service.

Comment: Create shared service and inject into `providers` property of `ngmodule` after this import  service into your `component` then you don't need to refresh whole page to load data.

Comment: U need to create a global data service to get the above result.

Answer (score 1):

Create a resolver guard and use it in your route configuration for TeamsComponent. Also, create a service that will do the data retrieval and inject it into the resolver. This service can either make a new request for data each time the user navigates to this route or cache the data and provide them to your TeamComponent on each subsequent visit of the route.

Take a look at this sample app that illustrates the general use of the resolver guard: https://github.com/Farata/angulartypescript/tree/master/code-samples/chapter4/router-advanced-samples/src/app/resolver.

But if you want to implement an injectable service with cache, take a look at the code in data.resolver2.ts and data.service.ts.

Comment: thank for your solution but could you just elaborate a little more on the specific steps?
I already have a service which grabs the data from a firestore

`

`

Comment: In my DataService, I read a large 48MB file into a variable myData, which serves as a cache https://github.com/Farata/angulartypescript/blob/master/code-samples/chapter4/router-advanced-samples/src/app/resolver/data.service.ts. 

When the user will navigate to my DataComponent for the first time, the service will read this large file. But if I navigate to another route and then return to DataComponent, the if-statement in the service will see that myData is not false, and will return its data without reading the file again.

Comment: If I understand well you cache the data and check if it still there. If it is you don't load it again. 

From what I see my question is different. I inject the data service in my component, I cache the data in this.teams but when I navigate to another page and come back the data is gone. 

Tried to solve it with other lifecycle hooks but they all seem to be called only once on creation.

Do I miss something here?

Comment: Yes, you miss the fact that I cache the data in the singleton service that survives component creations and destructions.